# Python name project

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that will ask a question if the user wants to add a name to a list edit a name from the list delete a name or display the list. I got a little bit of it I am having an issue making the question reappear after the request is complete. So after "1" is pressed and the action is done i want to question to appear again until the user quits the program.

here is what I have

```
#Creating a Searching?

names = []
answer = input("Create An Entry [Press 1] \nDisplay List [Press 2] \nEdit an Entry           [Press 3] \nRemove Entry [Press 4] \nQuit [Press 5]")

# IF creating 

if answer == "1" : 
    # collect information

    firstname = input("What is the persons first name? ")

    #add data

    names.append(firstname)
    answer = input("Create An Entry [Press 1] \nDisplay List [Press 2] \nEdit an Entry [Press 3] \nRemove Entry [Press 4] \nQuit [Press 5]")

# Display Data

elif answer == "2" :

print(names)
answer = input("Create An Entry [Press 1] \nDisplay List [Press 2] \nEdit an Entry [Press 3] \nRemove Entry [Press 4] \nQuit [Press 5]")


# USER Quit 

elif answer == "5":
    exit()
```

Comment: why not use a while loop?

Comment: @Bartlomiej Lewandowski i am really new to python how would i do this

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while

Comment: read through the python tutorials, a lot of useful stuff can be found there: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need a while loop:

```
while True:
    answer = input("Create An Entry [Press 1] \nDisplay List [Press 2] \nEdit an Entry [Press 3] \nRemove Entry [Press 4] \nQuit [Press 5]")
    # collect information
    if answer == "1": 
        firstname = input("What is the persons first name? ")
        names.append(firstname) # add data
    # Display Data
    elif answer == "2":
        print(names)
    # USER Quit 
    elif answer == "5":
        exit() # Or just break
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop.

```
while True:

    answer = raw_input("Create An Entry [Press 1] \nDisplay List [Press 2] \nEdit an Entry           [Press 3] \nRemove Entry [Press 4] \nQuit [Press 5]")

[Keep the rest as you had it before]

    # USER Quit 

    elif answer == "5":
        break
```

And remove the second (and third):

```
answer = input("Create An Entry [Press 1] \nDisplay List [Press 2] \nEdit an Entry           [Press 3] \nRemove Entry [Press 4] \nQuit [Press 5]")
```

Comment: the program wont show the question at all now for some reason

Comment: you need to use `raw_input` rather than `input` here

Answer (score 0):

```
name_list = []
help_msg = """Create An Entry [Press 1] \n
Display List [Press 2]
Edit an Entry [Press 3]
Remove Entry [Press 4]
Quit [Press 5]: """

while True:
    answer = raw_input(help_msg)
    if answer is not '5':
        if answer is '2':
            print "Current list: " + ', '.join(name_list)
            continue
        name_list.append(answer)
    else:
        break

print "Final list: " + ', '.join(name_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea...just use a while loop. You also must change all your `input()` stuff to `raw_input()`. Here is everything you wrote so it will work without fixing up your code to make it better. You're new, you should do that yourself to learn, but this way you can at least run your code:

```
names = []
inputting = True
while inputting:
    answer = raw_input("Create An Entry [Press 1] \nDisplay List [Press 2] \nEdit an Entry           [Press 3] \nRemove Entry [Press 4] \nQuit [Press 5]")

    # IF creating 

    if answer == "1" : 
        # collect information

        firstname = raw_input("What is the persons first name? ")

        #add data

        names.append(firstname)
    elif answer == "2" :
        print(names)
        answer = raw_input("Create An Entry [Press 1] \nDisplay List [Press 2] \nEdit an Entry [Press 3] \nRemove Entry [Press 4] \nQuit [Press 5]")


    # USER Quit 

    elif answer == "5":
        inputting = False
```